# How do I change the default view on my contacts object?

Tags: contact, event, list-view, npsp

This might be a very easy answer, but none of the solutions I have found seem to work for me because they're all from around 2013. I am using Salesforce Lightning and every time I go to my Contacts page or my Events page, I get a list of "Recently Viewed" items. I just want all of the items to show up by default. (AKA "All Contacts", "All Events") It has just become a very tedious task to change it every time I look at the records of those objects.

**Any Ideas?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think that's a default behavior.

Comment: That SUCKS if it's the case :/

Comment: you could post an Idea here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch or vote for similar ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This gets you most of what you want:

- Click Contacts->All Contacts (or open Contacts and change Recently Viewed to All Contacts).
- Click the down arrow next to Contacts on the nav bar and you'll see "+Open All Contacts in New Tab".   Do this.
- You can make this new tab a permanent part of your nav bar by clicking the down arrow on the new tab and selecting "Add All Contacts to Nav Bar."  You can also sort your tabs so that this one comes before the default Contacts tab.